# PerformanceProgressBar eats 50% of CPU even when invisible

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using the PerformanceProgressBar control from the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone.
I am observing that once a page with a PerformanceProgressBar is shown, the CPU in the emulator goes to 50% and stays there even after the IsIndedeterminate / Visibility / Enabled properties have been disabled.

Has anyone else observed this?

Not sure whether this is an emulator behavior only or it happens on the phone as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

When using the PerformanceProgressbar you should not only change the visibility state, but change the IsIndeterminate property accordingly. If you make the bar visible set IsIndeterminate to true, if you hide it, set IsIndeterminate to false. That should solve your problem.

Comment: I actually did set IsIndeterminate to true first thing. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to do the trick. The only way to have the CPU go down is to comment out the control.

Comment: Just checking, do you also set IsIndeterminate to false when hiding the control? That's essential here, hiding it without setting IsIndeterminate to false will keep hogging the CPU

Answer (score 2):

How are you measuring the emulator CPU? Are you just measuring your PC CPU when running the emulator? If so, this is not a reliable measure of the real performance. A much better way t gauge the performance of your application is to enable the [frame rate counters](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/). Look specifically at the render (or compositor) thread and UI thread frame rates. The performance progress bar should not have an impact on the UI thread frame rate, because it is designed so that it can be updated via the render / compositor thread.

Answer (score -1):

**Any** Storyboard-based animation (PerformanceProgressBar incl.) must necesarily perform badly as it is run on a privileged thread. If you want to know more or read about the alternatives, look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/WP7-Animations.aspx).

For fast info look at the table at the very end of the article. PerfProgressBar really takes away ~50% of the CPU, which is notably better than standard ProgressBar (>60%), but a lot worse than the other possibilities.

But: The numbers refer to the device. In case of the emulator the loss is much lower. At least in my concrete case. In general, I would not take performance numbers measured on the emulator too seriously.

Benchmark application described in the article is part of the Resco Mobile Forms Toolkit samples. That app uses this code for PerformanceProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar Style="{StaticResource PerformanceProgressBar}"
    Width="250" Margin="0" Padding="10"
    IsIndeterminate="{Binding ElementName=PerfProgressCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}"
    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=PerfProgressCheckBox, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource TrueVis}}" />
```

I can assure you that PerfProgressBar does not take any CPU while inactive. This holds true both on the device and emulator. I would look for a problem in your code.

Comment: I think this answer is over-complicating things. "Perform badly" is a bit harsh - it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you want smooth animations, or low  CPU? Also saying that the PerformanceProgressBar is "much worse" again depends on what you're trying to achieve. I think we can agree that the standard ProgressBar isn't a recommended option though.

Comment: For dozens of years I always tried to optimize my progress indicators to take less than 1%. Now, I have to be happy with something that goes up to 50%. Perhaps I getting too old... I of course agree that those 50% will be momentarily observable only when your app really needs CPU, which is often not the case. But unnecessary battery drainage will be there always and this also used to be one of the central PDA problems.

Comment: Otherwise y are right that the answer is side-tracking. I should have written only the bottom half.

Comment: It has to be said I was surprised at how much CPU these progress bars use.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem in my code would be, as CPU won't go up the moment I comment out the PerformanceProgressBar control. But I will double check.